# inline "using myClass = Namespace.ClassName" possible?

Tags: c#, alias

is it possible to define `using` inline (instead of putting this command in the top of the `c#` file) , like:

```
private void smth()
{
    using XYZ  = OtherNameSpace.ClassName;
    XYZ.Hello(); ...
}
```

or what can I do to make "aliased" class/namespaces inline?

Comment: like always with my questions, other answer's author commenting -  "why i need this" ...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The answer is in the [official docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/using-directive):

> The `using` directive can appear:
>
> - At the beginning of a source code file, before any namespace or type definitions.
> - In any namespace, but before any namespace or types declared in this namespace.

Comment: thanks, but what is solution to my question? what should i do?

Comment: Why don't you just move `using XYZ  = OtherNameSpace.ClassName;` to the top of the file?

Comment: well... i've asked how to avoid that, and you're asking me why i dont use what i wan to avoid. 
well, thanks for response anyway.

Comment: To clarify, the answer to your question "*is it possible to define using inline*" is no.